# ColdFusion: Invoke cffunction from the same component

Tags: coldfusion, functional-programming, composition

This question might be naive as I'm new to ColdFusion programming.

I have a task for which I have written a function, `f1`, inside a component. I want to call `f1` from another function, `f2` defined in the same component.

`f2` is being called in a cfm file.

My question - Is this the right way to do it? Can I invoke `f1` from `f2`?

I can as well merge `f1` into `f2`, but I would like keep `f1` as a separate function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can call f1 from f2 in ColdFusion if both functions are part of the same component. (They don't have to be in the same component, but if they are, the answer is always yes.)

```
 <cffunction name="f2">
    ...
    <cfset result_of_f1 = f1()>
    ...
 </cffunction>

 <cffunction name="f1">
    ...
 </cffunction>
```

There are lots of good reasons to call one function from another. It's called [function composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_(computer_science)).

Comment: Yeah, I got it now.

Its something like 

<cfinvoke method="functionName" ...>
</cfinvoke>

thanx

Comment: You don't actually need to use cfinvoke to call the second function unless you need a new instance of the object.  You can simply call it like any other function (as Patrick shows in his example).

Comment: saved my day... i was this.f1()-ing for the last half hour

Answer (score 0):

In Coldfusion 10 and Railo 4, you can create composed functions using the [Underscore.cfc library](http://russplaysguitar.github.com/UnderscoreCF/#compose):

```
_ = new Underscore();// instantiate the library

f1 = function (message) {
   return "hello " & message;
};

f2 = function (toOutput) {
   writeOutput(toOutput);
};

sayHelloTo = _.compose(f2, f1);

sayHelloTo("world!");// output: "hello world!"
```

(Note: I wrote the Underscore.cfc library)